# How to Insert or Update(NOT INSERT ONLY) using saveAll() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository

I have a table called `User`

I am working on a task where I want to insert multiple users from `CSV/XLSX` file.

I am able to save all the records by

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();


for (int i = 0; i < worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
                User user = new User();
                XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);
                user.setName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                userList.add(user);
            }
userRepository.saveAll(userList);
```

But now problem is that, in case if the file contains duplicate records or if I try to insert the same user again then it is also saved in table, and I don't want that.

**I want to keep the users with no duplicate names.**

My entity is simple with fields like

```
private Long userId;
private String name;
```

Let me know how can I avoid duplicate records insertion.

Any help would be appreciated.

**NOTES:**

I know how to remove duplicates from the arraylist. It's not the problem. The problem is if I try to add records from the new `CSV/XLSX` file and if that file has the same names which are available in the table, then I don't want to insert those names in the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();


for (int i = 0; i < worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            User user = new User();
            XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);

            User testUser = userList.get(userList.size()-1) //returns the last user
            testUser.setName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());

            if (userList.contains(testUser)) continue; //skips

            user.setName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
            userList.add(user);
        }
userRepository.saveAll(userList);
```

Now in simple words you get the last user you saved and add it in the variable testUser in order to get the last id, and then you set the Name and check if that user already exists

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `List<User>`, I suggest you use a `Set<User>` and override hashCode() and equals() as per your requirements.

After reading that note part, if you want to insert only new names in your table without changing the entity structure, you can do something like,

```
interface UserRepository extends JPARepository {
  public List<User> findByName(List<String> names);
}
```

You can use the above method to get records of names which are already present form your unsaved list of users, remove duplicates and save the remaining ones.